# Installing Shorewall on Debian stable

Tags: debian, firewall, shorewall

I'm going to install Shorewall on a Debian stable Linux box. The shorewall version in the stable repositories is 4.6.4.3-2.

[Shorewall website](http://shorewall.net/Install.htm#Debian) suggests to pin apt preferences and force the download of the new Shorewall version from testing repos.

```
Package: shorewall
Pin: release o=Debian,a=testing
Pin-Priority: 700
```

Have you ever done something like that and do you think it is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a common way if one is running `Debian stable`, but needs a more recent version of a specific software. The [backports](https://backports.debian.org/) mechanism is the way to go, but there are no backports provided for shorewall. So, go ahead and guck luck; I'm quite sure it will work flawlessly.